# Date not correct in custom Wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am working on a custom Wordpress loop that displays gig dates. Nearly everything works correctly, however I am having trouble splitting the ACF date into separate month and date span tags.

It seems to apply one date to all of the posts within the loop, instead of a separate date per post.

I am thinking this might be because the gig date is being fetched at the beginning? I have tried fetching the gig date within the loop but this doesn't seem to work either.

My loop is as follows:

```
<ul class="dates>

    <?php 

        $today = date('Ymd');
        $date = new DateTime(get_field('gig-date'));

        $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post_type' => 'gigs',
            'showposts' => 2,
            'meta_key' => 'gig-date',  
            'meta_compare' => '>',  
            'meta_value' => date("Ymd"),
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        ));

        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); { 
    ?>

        <li>
            <div class="date">
                <span class="day"><?php echo $date->format('d'); ?></span>
                <span class="month"><?php echo $date->format('M'); ?></span>
            </div>
        </li>

    <?php } endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: Put the `$date` variable inside the while loop to get their appropriate values for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted my loop and placed the date request after the while loop:

```
<?php 
    $today = date('Ymd');
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_type' => 'gigs',
        'showposts' => 2,
        'meta_key' => 'gig-date',  
        'meta_compare' => '>',  
        'meta_value' => date("Ymd"),
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    ));

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); {

    $date = get_field('gig-date', false, false);
    $date = new DateTime($date);
?>
```